# How do you make local storage persist after the app has been closed in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using the package localstorage - https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/localstorage#-installing-tab-

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:localstorage/localstorage.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

final LocalStorage storage = new LocalStorage("level");

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //storage.setItem("level", 0);
    printStorage();
  }

  void printStorage() {
    print("level stored: " + storage.getItem("level").toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("LocalStorage Example"),
      ),
      body: Center(

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When `storage.setItem("level", 0)` is not commented out the app works fine and prints out "level stored: 0". However after closing the app, commenting out `storage.setItem("level", 0)`, saving the app and rerunning the app the app prints out "level stored: null".

How do you make the storage persist from the last time the app was run?

I am using the Xcode iPhone simulator.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By looking at the package’s source code it looks like you’re not giving it enough time to load the data from the underlying async call. That’s why it exposes a flag property for you to check if it’s ready to perform read/write operations.

Just use it before printing as so:

```
storage.ready.then((_) => printStorage());
```

Comment: After some confusion on my end I can confirm this worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had similar questions, but after hours of testing and digging around, I can confirm that the localstorage package does persist data even after the app has been closed. If you want to see the actual database file for testing purposes (you can see the contents change live during iOS simulation) look here on macOS:

```
/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/SOMEDEVICENUMBER/data/Containers/Data/Application/SOMEAPPLICATIONNUMBER/Documents/level.json
```

So this means it just becomes a matter of waiting the few nanoseconds for the localstorage connection to be ready before trying to read and use the values.  Being new to Dart/Flutter, for me this means experimenting with the correct combination and location of async/await, or Future/then.

For example, this change will work correctly in your sample app:

```
  void printStorage() async {

    //this will still print null:
    print("before ready: " + testDb.getItem("level").toString());

    //wait until ready
    await storage.ready;

    //this will now print 0
    print("after ready: " + testDb.getItem("level").toString());
  }
```

In my actual app, if I forget to correctly place an "await" or "then", I get a lot of null errors before the actual value gets retrieved/assigned.

BTW in your file (level.json) you have only one element, {“level”, “0”}. For this scenario with simple data needs, using the shared_preferences package is an alternative consideration. But I like localstorage because it is clean and simple.